# How to select symbols onWorkspaceSymbol

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am developing an extension for visual studio code using language server protocol, and I am including the support for "Go to symbol in workspace". My problem is that I don't know how to select the matches...
Actually I use this function I wrote:

```
function IsInside(word1, word2)
{
    var ret = "";
    var i1 = 0;
    var lenMatch =0, maxLenMatch = 0, minLenMatch = word1.length;
    for(var i2=0;i2<word2.length;i2++)
    {
        if(word1[i1]==word2[i2])
        {
            lenMatch++;
            if(lenMatch>maxLenMatch) maxLenMatch = lenMatch;
            ret+=word1[i1];
            i1++;
            if(i1==word1.length)
            {
                if(lenMatch<minLenMatch) minLenMatch = lenMatch;
                // Trying to filter like VSCode does.
                return maxLenMatch>=word1.length/2 && minLenMatch>=2?  ret : undefined;
            }
        } else
        {
            ret+="Z";
            if(lenMatch>0 && lenMatch<minLenMatch)
                minLenMatch = lenMatch;
            lenMatch=0;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

That return the sortText if the word1 is inside the word2, undefined otherwise. My problem are cases like this:

[image: **strong text**]

My algorithm see that 'aller' is inside C**all**S**er**ver, but the interface does not mark it like expected.

There is a library or something that I must use for this? the code of VSCode is big and complex and I don't know where start looking for this information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode's API docs for `provideWorkspaceSymbols()` provide the following guidance (which I don't think your example violates):

> The `query`-parameter should be interpreted in a relaxed way as the editor will apply its own highlighting and scoring on the results. A good rule of thumb is to match case-insensitive and to simply check that the characters of query appear in their order in a candidate symbol. Don't use prefix, substring, or similar strict matching.

These docs were added in response to [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34605), where somebody had very much the same issue as you.

Having a brief look at VSCode sources, internally it seems to use `filters.matchFuzzy2()` for the highlighting (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/314cc521d8ce0c55773850ef520095afde33a62c/src/vs/workbench/parts/search/browser/openSymbolHandler.ts#L209) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/01aff5ab6c9d76177e8c42a80be7eff711c14355/src/vs/base/common/filters.ts#L350)). I don't think it's exposed in the API, so you would probably have to copy it if you wanted the behavior to match exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I see that github should be only for issue report and I did not search inside issues...